# Will Directory.EnumerateFiles work in a folder where new files are continually being added in?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, file-io

I have a folder which has many files. Files are continually being dropped into this folder from an external process.

I need to pick up each file one at a time and process them.

I was going to use GetFiles() but discovered EnumerateFiles() which seems better since it doesn't wait on the string array being fully populated before being able to work with the contents.

Will EnumerateFiles be able to cope with the fact that new files will be getting written to this folder continually? How will it behave?

My processor will work as a Windows Service and so when it gets to the end of the files in the Enumerable, it will then run again x seconds later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a file system watcher:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

And listen to a `Changed` or `Created` Event.

Comment: +1 File System Watcher is a much better way of doing something when a file is added than polling the directory

Comment: In the past, we've used a FileWatcher type solution but it has meant that if the Windows Service is stopped, we need to move out all the files and move them back in again in order to get them to start processing again... is there a way to prevent this being needed?

Comment: Also, I read that FileSystemWatcher is unreliable with network shares, which is what I will be using...

Comment: If you think `FileSystemWatcher` is unreliable, you might create a wrapper that uses it together with a timer to poll the directory and find possible missed files. Future versions of .NET could improve the `FileSystemWatcher` and no more require you to do the polling.

Comment: I'm not too sure about having another timer to pull file list. Pulling is always a bad idea, unless you set a pretty reasonable interval.

Comment: @SebastianSiek: It is a bad idea, if you have alternatives. But if `FileSystemWatcher` is broken, then you've no chance I think.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have used FSW with network share path. Where did you find out that there's a problem. Also make sure you use UNC paths, and not use mapped drive path

Comment: Just Googled and saw a few people saying they'd been let down by the FSW and that it needed restarted regularly if too many files arrive at once. I'd prefer to have a scheduled system which looks for any files in the folder to be processed. If there are some, it processes them. If files are already being processed, it waits for the current process to finish. That was my reason for using a Windows Service, what are the downsides of this way?

Comment: well. if FSW is being used in a wrong way then YES - You might loose the notifications !!! As long as you don't perform any time consuming operation on FSW event, it should work perfectly fine. Problem starts when whatever you need to do when event fires takes time. Again - the way you implement is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation does not mention that being a problem. I would expect it to return all the files that were there until it finished executing. The only difference between the two is the way they return the enumeration.

[FileWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) as mentioned in the first answer is the way to go.